# Is it possible to create two or more relations to a model in prisma?

Tags: graphql, datamodel, prisma, prisma-graphql

I'm trying to create two relations to a model in *datamodel.prisma*

**datamodel.prisma**

```
type User {
  id: ID! @id 
  user_id: String! @unique
  username: String!
  email: String! @unique
}

type Operation {
  id: ID! @id
  teams: [User] @relation(link: INLINE)
  created_by: User @relation(link: INLINE)
}
```

When I try to deploy this is the error I'm getting

**Error**

```
Errors:

  Operation
    ✖ The relation field `teams` must specify a `@relation` directive: `@relation(name: "MyRelation")`
    ✖ The relation field `created_by` must specify a `@relation` directive: `@relation(name: "MyRelation")`
```

What I want to achieve is an operation can have multiple members(one to many) and can only be created by one member(one to one). How can I achieve this in **Prisma**?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try creating it like this:

```
type User {
  id: ID! @id
  user_id: String! @unique
  username: String!
  email: String! @unique
}

type Operation {
  id: ID! @id
  teams: [User] @relation(name: "Teams", link: TABLE)
  created_by: User @relation(name: "Createdby", link: TABLE)
}
```

The `name` field is required while creating multiple relations to the same model.
Also I'm assuming you are using Postgres.

Comment: I am using Mongo. So I changed your answer a bit to work for me but I am getting this error now ``` You are trying to set the relation 'Createdby' from `Operation` to `User` and are only providing a relation directive with a name on `Operation`. Please also provide the same named relation directive on the relation field on `User` pointing towards `Operation`. ```

Comment: Does this work: `type User {
  id: ID! @id
  user_id: String! @unique
  username: String!
  email: String! @unique
  operation_owner: Operation @relation(name: "Createdby", link: TABLE)
}

type Operation {
  id: ID! @id
  teams: [User] @relation(name: "Teams", link: TABLE)
  created_by: User @relation(name: "Createdby", link: TABLE)
}`